# SQL Query WHERE clause is a parameter

Tags: mysql

Can you please help me solve the problem I am having with my query. I am very new in Database programming and I thoroughly search the web for the help but none solve my issue. I am fed up and wondering if this is even possible.
What I want to accomplish is to execute a SELECT query where the column to search is to be supplied on runtime. Like this one:

```
SELECT *
FROM myTable
WHERE @columnToSeach = @_ColumnName
```

Advice is really appreciated as my brain is practically bleeding on this one.

Comment: This is not possible using parameters.

Comment: Okay. thanks..I will try to look on Dynamic SQL. I might find something there that could help me.

Comment: @MitchWheat: Dynamic SQL is prone to sql injection attacks. I would not provide it as advice without this warning.

Comment: There's plenty of examples for this, and please choose tags correctly. Is this MySQL or SQL Server question?

Comment: @ Zohar Peled: I'm aware of that.

Comment: Why MySQL and SQL Server tags, are both products really onvolved? (I guess one of them should be removed. Add sql tag instead.)

Comment: @MitchWheat I'm sure **you** are aware of that, but I can't say the same about the **OP**. This is why I wrote my comment - sure the easy way is to use dynamic sql and it will solve this problem, but I think that the OP should be aware of the risks involved.

Comment: @ Zohar Pele: Please also note I said "search for 'Dynamic SQL"" not "use it blindly"!  In fact, the poster should read this: http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html

Comment: @MitchWheat Ok, I accept that.

Comment: MySQL Server @JamesZ

Answer (score 1):

A very quick solution would be:

```
execute ('SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE ' + @columnToSeach + '=' + @_ColumnName)
```

Comment: I didn't notice you want to prevent SQL injection and I assumed you are the only one who gonna use it.
Anyway, you might use some validations like:
`if(not charindex(' ', @_ColumnName) > 0)`